# m.2 SATA to PCIe adapter

Tags: ssd, raid, sata, pci-express, m.2

I bought two m.2 SATA SSD `SanDisk SSD x400 128Gb`.

But my motherboard `Asus Maximus IX Hero` has only one m.2 SATA port `m.2.1`. Second m.2 port `m.2.2` accept only PCIe devices.

Now I want to buy `m.2 SATA to PCIe` adapter or something like that. Besides of that I have a question:

Which type of adapters is better, of there's no big difference? I saw `m.2 SATA to PCIe x4` adapters and `m.2 SATA to regular SATA 2.5 inch` adapters. The main idea is to make RAID with both those SSD.

Comment: "Which adapter should I buy (name or model)?" - This question is out of scope here at Superuser.  We will be unable to answer this question, due to it being a hardware recommendations, questions seeking hardware recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.  "Will it work in RAID, even if those SSDs will be installed in different ports?" - It will not be possible to setup a hardware RAID in the configuration you describe unless you use a software RAID.  All devices must be connected to the same hardware RAID to use to configure it

Comment: I think you've got your interfaces backwards... "_M.2 to PCIe_" certainly implies to me that you want to connect to an M.2 socket on the motherboard, and produce a PCIe socket to accept a PCIe card. There's no "correct" way, but typically you'll see such adaptors listed with interfaces from the core outwards.

Comment: PS: Yes, you can get a "_PCIe to M.2 (SATA)_" adapter (try google).

Comment: @Attie My English isn't perfect) So, I have `m.2 SATA SSD` (not `m.2 PCe SSD`, which is important). I have only one comparable port on my motherboard for that, which means that I can't use second SSD. I know that there's exists adapters, in which I can install my second `m.2 SATA SSD`, and then connect this adapter into motherboard, but I'm not that it'll work or if it'll work in RAID.

Comment: I don't wanna make mistake again and buy device which I'll unable to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a PCIe add-in card, that provides an M.2 socket which supports an M.2 SATA SSD.

I can't reasonably recommend a product - partly because of limited information you've shared, partly because that's not what this site is for. However, you should look for an add-in card like the one pictured below:

[image: PCIe to M.2 SATA]

This particular card has two M.2 slots - one that supports PCIe devices, and one that supports SATA devices.

You've mentioned in a comment that you're hoping to use the motherboards RAID (not something I'd typically recommend). The card pictured above achieves the SATA support by simply passing through the SATA signals - you'd connect the included SATA cable to an appropriate motherboard SATA connector. This is important if you're keen to use the motherboard's RAID functionality.

The alternate approach that some cards take is for the PCIe card to have a SATA controller on-board. These cards will not have the SATA connector on board, and will not let you do what you want, so watch out.

---

It's also worth pointing out that the M.2 slot on your motherboard that supports SATA will be doing pretty much exactly the same thing, it's just that the signals are all on one board.

**NOTE**: this means that using "*SATA mode*" on the motherboard's M.2 slot will likely "*use up*" one of the SATA connectors, so make sure you read the manual!

Comment: Thank much, that's what I want. You said `not something I'd typically recommend` - why? And can I somehow determine that adapter has its own SATA controller (to don't use SATA cord)?

Comment: On-board RAID tends to be a 'lite' offering... If you're looking to Stripe (RAID0) your SSDs, then this is not really a good idea - If you're looking to Mirror (RAID1), then it's probably not so bad.

Comment: If you're after an adapter that "_has its own SATA controller_", then you will _not_ be able to use the motherboard's RAID, and you may run into boot issues with drivers, etc... if you are planning to make this SSD your boot device.